# Project with path ':spotify-app-remote' could not be found in project ':app'.?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, spotify, aar

I am  developing android an app using Spotify SDK and I am following [quick start guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/)

but when I have imported .aar and sync project I am getting the following error

A project with path ':spotify-app-remote' could not be found in project ':app'.

following image below my folder structure from android studio [image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `include ':spotify-app-remote'` in your `settings.gradle` file.